# How to write a dummy java API to returning a string and call it from a Camunda service task

Tags: java, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to write a dummy java api and call it from the Camunda workflow

```
@WebServlet("/Avg")
```

public class Avg extends HttpServlet{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID =1L;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,IOException{
    ProcessEngine engine =BpmPlatform.getDefaultProcessEngine();

    List<LockedExternalTask> tasks =engine.getExternalTaskService().fetchAndLock(1,"some-random-id")
    .topic("payeeavg", 2000).execute();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int number = rnd.nextInt(999999);
    String.format("%06d", number+50000);
    LockedExternalTask lockedExternalTask =(LockedExternalTask) tasks;
    engine.getExternalTaskService().complete(lockedExternalTask.getId(), "some-random-id");
}
```

}

I have tried writing this but don't know how to connect it to camunda.

```
execution.getBpmnModelElementInstance();
    String vcUniqueTransID ="1234";
    String payeeavg = "123";
    String Comment = "Fraud";
    Boolean Approve = true;
    String Approvee ="No";
```

I want to write a dummy API which will give a output of string value and it should be called in the service task to get the payeeavg variable.

I have seen the camunda external task doc but i cant understand how to write it and connect it

if anyone can help or share a example how to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you want to call a REST service you exposed from within a service task?

Here is an example how to do this:
https://github.com/camunda-consulting/code/tree/master/snippets/rest-service-task-spring